# Run code upon APEX$ROW_STATUS = "Unchanged"

Tags: oracle-apex, interactive-grid

I'm using oracle apex version 22.2. I'm trying run conditional code upon ALL rows that are stored within my interactive grid. I see that the APEX$ROW_STATUS only can return a status of: updated, created, deleted. But what does it return if the row is unchanged? Is there any way I can still use the IG to run code on rows that have not been modified? I thought an else statement should capture what I was looking for.

```
-- There is no "when ('C', 'U')" function available
case :APEX$ROW_STATUS

when 'C' then
    insert into memmgr.payout_rates_reseller
        (payoutratekeyid, resellerkeyid, buyratetype, percentover, buyrate, risklevel)
    values 
        (:P253_PAYOUTRATEKEYID, :resellerkeyid, :buyratetype, to_number(:percentover)*100, to_number(:buyrate)*100, 'N')
    returning keyid into :keyid;
when 'U' then
    insert into memmgr.payout_rates_reseller
        (payoutratekeyid, resellerkeyid, buyratetype, percentover, buyrate, risklevel)
    values 
        (:P253_PAYOUTRATEKEYID, :resellerkeyid, :buyratetype, to_number(:percentover)*100, to_number(:buyrate)*100, 'N')
    returning keyid into :keyid;
when 'D' then
    null; -- Don't do anything because we're just focused on inserting new rates
else
    insert into memmgr.payout_rates_reseller
        (payoutratekeyid, resellerkeyid, buyratetype, percentover, buyrate, risklevel)
    values 
        (:P253_PAYOUTRATEKEYID, :resellerkeyid, :buyratetype, to_number(:percentover)*100, to_number(:buyrate)*100, 'N')
    returning keyid into :keyid;
end case;
```

Comment: afaik If row is unchanged it is not submitted to the server so it cannot be captured.